# Let $a\in R^m$. Can we prove that $f'(a)=0$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

Let $a\in R^m$,  $f \in C^{1}(R^m,R^m)$. If every open ball $B_{\epsilon}(a)$ contains 2 different points $x,y$ s.t. $f(x)=f(y)$, can we prove that $f'(a)=0$?

I solved the situation when $m=1$. Since $\forall \epsilon>0$, there exist $x \neq y$ s.t. $f(x)=f(y)$, we construct 2 sequences $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ by choosing $\epsilon_1=1$, $\epsilon_2=1/2, \cdots, \epsilon_n=1/n, \cdots$, and for $\epsilon_i=1/i$ picking the corresponding $x_i , y_i \in B_{\epsilon_i}(a)$ s.t. $x_i \neq y_i$ and $f(x_i)=f(y_i)$. It is clear that $x_n \rightarrow a$ and $y_n \rightarrow a$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. 
By Lagrange's theorem, there exists $\xi_n = x_n+ \theta (y_n-x_n)$ where $\theta \in [0,1]$ s.t. $f(y_n)-f(x_n)=f'(\xi_n)(y_n-x_n)$.  But $f(y_n)-f(x_n)=0$, hence $f'(\xi_n)=0$(when $m=1$). We again obtain a sequence $\{\xi_n\}$ where $\xi_n \rightarrow a$ and $f'(\xi_n)=0$. By continuity of $f'$, $f'(\xi_n) \rightarrow f'(a)$. Since $f'(\xi_n) \rightarrow 0$, we know that $f'(a)=0$.

I have some intuition about this problem. Since $f'$ exists, $f$ locally acts like a linear function. And the condition determines this linear function to be $0$, but I have no idea how to deal with a higher dimentional space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counterexample : $m=2$, $f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m)=(x_1,0,\ldots,0), a=(0,\ldots,0)$. Then $f(\varepsilon,0,\ldots,0)=f(a)$ for every $\varepsilon \gt 0$ but $f'(a)\neq 0$.

Comment: in other words: All we can show is that $f'(a)$ has non-trivial kernel

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Indeed, by the local inversion theorem.

Comment: ... and perhaps $f(x,y)=(x,0)$ is a less convoluted counterexample

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen This counterexample also has the merit of being more obviously generalizable to any dimension. I edited my answer to relfect this